# Make a JLabel disappear after a few seconds in java

Tags: java, timer, jframe, jlabel

So I want to make some kind of a JLabel that will appear and disappear after a few seconds once certain components are clicked. I used Swing Timer.
Here is my method which is handling this JLabel
`

```
public void Clicked(String dialog) {
        if(isStarted == true) { //Checking if any other component is clicked
            dialogue.setText(dialog);// setting text to the label which is the method argument
        }
        isStarted = false;
         t = new Timer(2500,new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dialogue.setText("");// disappearing the label after 2.5 seconds
        }
        
    });
         t.start();
         t.setRepeats(false);
    isStarted = true;
    }
```

`

It actually works fine but when I click 2 components at once, it kinda starts acting weirdly.

Comment: what does `it kinda starts acting weirdly` means?

Comment: the timer doesn't work properly like working for less period of time

Comment: “doesn’t work properly” is not information we can use.  What behavior, exactly, are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) section.

We don't make a `JLabel` disappear.  We change the text of the `JLabel` to blank.

I created a simple GUI to demonstrate how to use Swing `Timers`.

[image: Start]

After you press the "Display" `JButton`, the following text is displayed.

[image: See]

After 2.5 seconds, the following text is displayed.

[image: Don't]

After 2.5 seconds, the text is cleared.

The "trick" is setting a `boolean` in the original `ButtonListener` that causes the `actionPerformed` method to ignore repeated `JButton` presses.  The entire process runs from start to finish no matter how many times you press the `JButton` while the process is running.

Here's the complete runnable code.  I made the additional class an inner class so I could post the code as one block.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class DisappearingJLabelGUI implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new DisappearingJLabelGUI());
    }

    private JLabel textLabel;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Disappearing JLabel GUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 5, 5));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 5, 5));

        textLabel = new JLabel(" ");
        panel.add(textLabel);

        JButton button = new JButton("Display");
        button.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        panel.add(button);

        return panel;
    }

    public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        private boolean isRunning;

        public ButtonListener() {
            this.isRunning = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            if (!isRunning) {
                isRunning = true;
                textLabel.setText("Now, you see it.");
                Timer timer = new Timer(2500, new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                        Timer timer = (Timer) event.getSource();
                        timer.stop();
                        textLabel.setText("Now, you don't.");
                        timer = new Timer(2500, new ActionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                                Timer timer = (Timer) event.getSource();
                                timer.stop();
                                textLabel.setText(" ");
                                isRunning = false;
                            }
                        });
                        timer.start();
                    }
                });
                timer.start();
            }
        }

    }

}
```